# How do you adapt the saddle-point integration where the amplitude function has a phase shift?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, semiclassical

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be very appreciative. I have tried researching online, but I haven't been able to find many articles/textbooks which are helpful.

I am trying to do an integral of the following form:

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{i g(x)} dx . 
$$

For situations where $f(x)$ is slowly varying, the saddle-point solution to this system is well understood and easily searchable. I am interested, however, in the case where $f(x)$ is not necessarily a slow varying function of $x$. For example, if $f(x)$ is complex and passes through a minimum, $(i)$ its amplitude will vary at the minimum, and $(ii)$ it will undergo a fast $\pi$-phase jump.

My intuition tells me I should evaluate the integral as follows:

$$
I = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{\ln(f(x)) + i g(x)} dx.
$$

This is numerically difficult. Further, I think I am encountering trouble due to the second-order derivative of the total phase not being well-behaved.

If anyone has any advice on how to approach this problem, or have a handy reference, I will be immensely appreciative.

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer since I'm not 100% sure this is what you are asking. But, if I understand your problem correctly, you *can't* use the saddle point approximation (for more or less the reasons you are having problems), so you need another approach. In the WKB approximation in quantum mechanics, this type of problem is dealt with by Taylor expanding $f(x)$ in the region where it is rapidly varying, and then using "connection formulas" to connect this solution to stationary phase solutions valid when $f(x)$ is slowly varying.

Comment: See, eg, Section 3.3 of the Spring 2018 MIT Physics 8-06 course notes by Zwiebach (spring 2018): https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch3.pdf

Comment: Hi user139632. Welcome to Phys.SE. 1. What is the actual example that you're trying to do? 2. How does the expansion parameter (usually $\hbar$) enter the $f$ function? The second point is needed for the saddle-point approximation.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function that is not slowly varying, then write $f(x) = h(x) e^{-i g(x)}$. Now, you're just trying to integrate $h(x)$. Then, it seems that if $f(x)$ is not restricted at all you're just trying to find a general anti-derivative. So it seems the form you give does not offer any particular integration strategies without some assumption about $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I suppose I should be specific about $f(x)$. Assume that $f(x)$ is some envelope function which undergoes a minimum at some $x_0$, where it undergoes a phase shift of the form $\phi(x) = \arctan((x - x_0) / \sigma)$. Does that help specify the question, David?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this function. It sounds like you are saying $f(x)=a(x) e^{i\phi(x)}$, where $x$ is complex, and where $a(x)$ has a local minimum at $x_0$ and $\phi(x)$ is an ${\rm arctan}$. If so there are some subtleties, since ${\rm arctan}$ has a branch cut that needs to be handled carefully to do the integration. Additionally, while $a(x)$ may have a minimum, $df/dx$ won't be equal to $0$ at $x_0$ because the phase is changing. Can you maybe provide an explicit example of what you mean (even if your question is more general)?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the comment. Let's suppose that $g(x)$ is a quadratic function of $x$ (e.g. $g(x) = - \alpha x^2$). Further, let's focus on a simple case and ignore the envelope variations in $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = \arctan((x - x_0) / \sigma)$. Could you please explain how to handle the branch cut in the arctan function, or point me somewhere to read about it? I appreciate your feedback